# Handling overflow on fixed height, scrollable containers

Tags: css

I'm trying to annotate specific funtionality in an app, and the annotations appear to the side of a column of content. The column is a fixed height with custom scrollers, so I need overflow y to be auto or scroll - and overflow-x to be visible, so the annotation is visible.

I know this isn't possible by setting auto/visible on the same element, but I have seen solutions on SO where the column is set to overflow-y auto, and the wrapper is set to overflow visible - but I can't get it working.

I have a JSBin set up with my current implementation - https://jsbin.com/woduciv/edit?html,css,output

Essentially:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: visible;
}
.column__content {
  position: static;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to have the x axis visibly, and y scroll enabled?

Thank you :)

Comment: I tried with different possible options, but noting worked out without using js and some fixed position. Looking forward for any workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Unica One', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
}
.custom-panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}
.custom-panel p {
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="panel custom-panel">
    <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thanks Sangrai, but that seems to only display a block of text with x & y axis scrollbars.